# Cannot identify data structure from JSON to deserialize into object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Having issue with deserializing json string into object.
The main issue is that I can not identify what type of object this string represents:

```
string jsonDataText = @"{""sun"":""heat"", ""planet"":""rock"", ""earth"":""water"", ""galaxy"":""spiral""}";
```

It looks like List of KeyValuePair objects, but when I try to deserialize by using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
var clone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>(jsonDataText);
```

I have got an exception:

```
 Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

Had also tried with Maps and string(multidimensional) arrays but got the same exception...

Comment: Did you try creating a class with sun, planet, earth, galaxy?

Comment: I think you mean `Dictionary<string, string>` Newtonsoft is pretty good at turning JSON objects into that model.

Comment: @BugFinder those names could be anything, I can not name it.

Comment: @er-sho I do not know, I'm not creator of that model, just need to work with it. I need to deserialize it and afterwards serialize (in same format) before sending to target server.

Comment: @VladacusB it wasnt clear from your post that these names are changing

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Dictionary< string,string > to me.

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonDataText);
```

Comment: Somehow I missed it, it is Dictionary, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With using `JObject` its easy to read any key/value pair from JSON.

So you no more need to identify what the type of your key/value pair in your json.

```
string jsonDataText = @"{""sun"":""heat"", ""planet"":""rock"", ""earth"":""water"", ""galaxy"":""spiral""}";

//Parse your json to dictionary
Dictionary<string, string> dict = JObject.Parse(jsonDataText).ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

You need to add this namespace to your program => `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Those variable names could be anything. They can not be hard coded.

Comment: @VladacusB, answer updated, but let me know what you want to do with data after getting it into dictionary?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like to me as a simple class.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("sun")]
    public string Sun { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("planet")]
    public string Planet { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("earth")]
    public string Earth { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("galaxy")]
    public string Galaxy { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize:

```
var clone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonDataText);
```

Comment: You got it all wrong, those variable names are not hard coded. They could be anything.

Comment: I appreciate the down vote, but you didnt mentioned this. If this is the situation, you should use a Dictionary<string, string>, as the others mentioned.